# Upgrading from CsvHelper, fix breaking changes

Tags: c#, nuget-package, csvhelper

As shown on the [GitHub of CsvHelper project](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1651) the config is read only now so I've moved the property initialization into the constructor. There is also a property which is now unsupported: **IgnoreQuotes**.

What's the new corrisponding parameter?

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                {
                    HasHeaderRecord = true,
                    BadDataFound = null,
                    Delimiter = ",",
                    Quote = '"',
                    
                    IgnoreQuotes = true

            };
```

Comment: from [Change log](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/), `IParserConfiguration.IgnoreQuotes` is simply removed. It's not moved not rename, it's gone. You perhaps have a simple [mre] , one line CSV that worked previously and not now

Comment: But the documentation still show the property https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration/ . It could be 2 nice report on the github.

Comment: I will try `ParserMode`. As it's the only add in the `IParserConfiguration`. That look related . But I didn't read the source code.

Comment: @DragandDrop thanks a lot, I will file an issue to him

Comment: If you come up with a solution please come back here it may be usefull to future reader.

Comment: The API docs haven't been updated in a while. The generator needs to be completely redone as it doesn't support a lot of the new C# features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `IgnoreQuotes` there are `ParserMode`s. As of version `21.1.0` there are 3 modes.

- RFC4180
- Escape
- NoEscape

`RFC4180` will treat fields like the "spec" says and expect double quotes around fields that contain a delimiter, newline or double quote. If a field has a double quote in it, it needs to be escaped (preceded) by a double quote.

`Escape` will use an escape character only and ignore the character immediately after the escape.

`NoEscape` will ignore double quotes and escape characters. This means a field can't contain a delimiter, double quote, or newline, as there is no way to escape them.

You can set the delimiter (string), quote (char), escape (char), and newline (string).